# Display Day names with wp_get_archives instead of date

Tags: archives

Im basically trying to show the archive for 1 week and instead of displaying the date, i want to display the day names. like monday-sunday.
right now im using this code

```
wp_get_archives('type=daily&format=option&show_post_count=1&cat=13703&limit=')
```

which displays this

```
11/05/2015 (39)
11/04/2015 (39)
11/03/2015 19)
11/02/2015 (17)
11/01/2015 (6)
10/31/2015 (16)
```

but my goal would be to have it like this

```
Tuesday (39)
Wednesday(39)
Thursday 19)
Monday (17)
Sunday (6)
Saturday (16)
```

would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no arguments you can pass to do this, and no obvious filters. However, if you dig through the source you will see:

```
1426            if ( ! $archive_date_format_over_ride ) {
1427                    $archive_day_date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
1428                    $archive_week_start_date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
1429                    $archive_week_end_date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );
1430            }
```

That value is used here:

```
1514    $text = mysql2date( $archive_day_date_format, $date );
```

To create the "text" of the link.

It is possible to filter the output of `get_option()` :)

```
function hack_date_format_wpse_207803() {
  return 'l';
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_date_format','hack_date_format_wpse_207803' );
wp_get_archives('type=daily&show_post_count=1&cat=13703&limit=');
remove_filter( 'pre_option_date_format','hack_date_format_wpse_207803' );
```

Your `format=` argument is preventing links. I removed that.

Comment: thanks but it doesnt work throws a internal server error

Comment: @user3646085 : Sorry, there was an error when I pasted it over. It should work now... works like a charm when I test it.

Comment: seems to be working but it outputs at the top of the header? lie its brekaing the function file

Comment: It will output wherever you put the `wp_get_archives()` code. If you've put that in the header that is where it will output. If you put that whole block in the functions file then yes, the archives will output when the functions file loads. This is "proof of concept". You have to adapt to your case, but usage is pretty basic. 1) Put the function definition in your `functions.php` file. 2) Put the rest where you want the code to execute. Or 3) Put the whole thing where you want the code to execute.